# How to install/active syslogd at iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, syslog, cydia

I need to install Syslogd to view iPhone/iPad logs.

I am trying this at Jailbroken device through Cydia.

I have searched several forum. Many people told that if I install crash reporter then Syslogd will be installed. Then, how to active or start Syslogd?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`syslogd` ("to /var/log/syslog") can be found in Cydia from Saurik's repo. To view it check your settings in Cydia and set the mode to developer to view all debugging software, support libraries, developer tools etc. Then when you have installed it all your logs are stored in `/var/log/syslog`.

Happy debugging ;P !